# SFINAE is not applied to auto generated special member function?

Tags: c++

```
class Myclass{
private:
    int i;
public:
    Myclass(){}
    Myclass(const Myclass &lvalue){} //<---
    template<typename T>Myclass(T& lvalue):i(lvalue){}
};

int main()
{
    Myclass a;
    Myclass b(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above fails to compile with:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Myclass’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

Is this a bug? I have tested it using g++ 5.3 and clang3.9

Comment: as per [cppreference], substitution occurs _all expressions used in a template parameter declaration_ (C++11) and _all types used in the template parameter declarations_. Your example is a failure outside of those cases.

Comment: What do you mean "if we comment this line"? You get the same behavior whether that line is present or not.

Comment: @camino when I compile your code with gcc 5.3, I get the same error with or without the line. The error goes away if I remove the `const`. Are you certain the code you are posting here is the code you are compiling?

Comment: (Original comment was supposed to have a link to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae))

Comment: @davmac I get the same error, sorry for confusing. I add const in the code here, but I didn't change the code in my editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, not a bug. And this has nothing to do with SFINAE.

Let's do overload resolution on:

```
Myclass b(a);
```

We have two viable overloads:

```
 Myclass(Myclass const&); // your copy ctor
 Myclass(Myclass& );      // your ctor template, with [T=Myclass]
```

Both are exact matches. One of the tiebreakers in picking the best viable candidate is to select the least cv-qualified reference - which in this case is the template. This ends up trying to initialize your `int` with a `Myclass`, hence the error. (Note, there is a tiebreaker to prefer non-templates to templates - but it's a lower ranked tiebreaker than the cv-qualification on the reference).

In this case, the solution would be to introduce SFINAE to disable this constructor in the case that it should use the copy ctor. That is:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible<T*, Myclass const*>::value>>
Myclass(T& );
```

And now this constructor won't be viable for `Myclass b(a)`.

Comment: why SFINAE is not happened here? "When substituting the deduced type for the template parameter fails, the specialization is discarded from the overload set instead of causing a compile error. " why the  specialization is  not discarded?

Comment: @camino There's no substitution failure. There's nothing that would cause `template<typename T>Myclass(T& lvalue)` to fail when `T=Myclass`.

Comment: so SFINAE only apply to function signature,it will not care about the function body, right?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are good, but I thought I'd add standard references to complement. The [latest draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match), section **Ranking implicit conversion sequences**, states:

> - Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>
>   - `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings ([dcl.init.ref]), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level
>       cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by `S2`
>       refers is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference
>       initialized by `S1` refers. [ *Example:*
>
>     ```
>     int f(const int &);
>     int f(int &);
>     int g(const int &);
>     int g(int);
>
>     int i;
>     int j = f(i);                   // calls f(int &)
>     ```